# TRY CATCH not Catching ERROR for TABLE DOES NOT EXIST

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, try-catch

When attempting to INSERT INTO a table that does not exist *(MigrationLog)* I expected the Try Catch to *catch* this error and execute the code within the CATCH Block however that is not occurring.  After the below script is run I'm left with hanging transactions and I am manually Rolling back the Transaction.

When the MigrationLog table does exist and I attempt to insert a varchar into an INT field that error is properly caught and the script behaves as expected.

Are there errors that are NOT caught by Try Catch blocks or am I doing this wrong? - Comments by Dan Guzman and Stu answered this question.  There are compile time and run time errors.

Since my error is due to the table not existing and is a Compilation Error the issue I am still having is the fact that the remainder of the script is still running due to it skipping the RETURN within the CATCH Block.  How do I stop the script from executing? The script cannot run without that table and needs to be exited.  I thought perhaps SET XACT_ABORT ON would be the solution however this setting says it is for Run Time Errors. How do I stop the remainder of the script from executing and also ROLLBACK the open transactions?  If Run Time errors are already caught by TRY CATCH Blocks my thought is this would be redundant.

The Error I receive is:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 14 Invalid object name 'MigrationLog'

```
/* DECLARE Individual Error Detail Variables */
DECLARE 
      @ErrorProcedure   VARCHAR(200)
    , @ErrorMessage     NVARCHAR(4000)
    , @ErrorSeverity    VARCHAR(20) /* Level aka Severity Level */
    , @ErrorState       VARCHAR(20)
    , @ErrorLine        VARCHAR(20);

/* Insert Main Log */
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY
        /* This will error due to the MigrationLog table not having been created */
        INSERT INTO MigrationLog (Status, Comments, CreatedDate, UpdatedDate)
        VALUES (0, 'Migration Testing', GetDate(), GetDate())

    END TRY
        
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK;
        PRINT 'Transaction ROLLED BACK in MigrationLog INSERT';

        /* Store Individual Error Details in variables for later output */
        SELECT
              @ErrorProcedure   = ERROR_PROCEDURE()
            , @ErrorMessage     = ERROR_MESSAGE()
            , @ErrorSeverity    = ERROR_SEVERITY()
            , @ErrorState       = ERROR_STATE()
            , @ErrorLine        = ERROR_LINE();
            --ERROR_NUMBER()    AS ErrorNumber,

        /* RAISE the Error */
        RAISERROR(N'An error occurred in %s Inserting the Main MigrationLog Record.  Level %s, State %s, Line %s, ErrorMsg: %s', 11, 2, @ErrorProcedure, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState, @ErrorLine, @ErrorMessage);
        Return;

    END CATCH /* END MigrationLog INSERT */

    COMMIT;

END

--SELECT @@TRANCOUNT;
```

Comment: This is a compilation error. The [doc states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#errors-unaffected-by-a-trycatch-construct): "The following types of errors are not handled by a CATCH block when they occur at the same level of execution as the TRY...CATCH construct: Compile errors, such as syntax errors, that prevent a batch from running."

Comment: This isn't a "catchable" error. This is a parsing error. The table doesn't exist at the time the batch is parsed and so the the **entire** batch fails; the `TRY...CATCH` is never entered.

Comment: This is a compile time not run time error, you can however run your insert in a separate session using `exec()` within the `try catch` and catch the error.

Comment: @Stu How would one detect a "compilation error" to then make sure there are no longer any OPEN Transactions?  If I have other scripting after this error I am finding that the rest of the script is still running due to it skipping over the RETURN within the CATCH.

Comment: @DanGuzman  I have updated sections of the original question.  What are your thoughts on SET XACT_ABORT ON?  It says this is for Run Time Errors however since my issue is a compilation error... how do I stop the rest of the script from executing and also ROLLBACK the open transactions?

Comment: @CodeNovice, you haven't shared the entire script. I assume the code in your question is part of a stored proc, you call the proc from an outer batch of statements, and the code in the outer batch continues after the proc compilation error. `SET XACT_ABORT ON` in the outer script will stop the entire batch after an error (including a compile error in the inner proc batch) and rollback the transaction (if any). But there will be no transaction to rollback unless one was started in the outer batch.